# Writing response from Java Http Server to jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, http, ibm-midrange

I wrote some Java program working on iSeries server. It can handle all Http requests to this server.
I also wrote Html page which is opened on local computer and I use some jQuery (Ajax) requests to iSeries server and I want to get some data from program which is running on it.

My server program sees that it gets some requests (POST and GET) with all parameters etc. and responses to it.

Unfortunately jQuery can't read answer data while simple Java program written and run on my local computer connects to iSeries server can read all responses from this server.

How can I write response in Java which will be avaiable to be read by jQuery?

Comment: Does this really relate to IBM i (iSeries)?

Comment: it is on iSeries machine so it's strictly related

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to process data in [JSON](http://json.org/) format in the client side with jQuery. Try to program your server-side to return your data in JSON format.

Comment: I use:
   $.getJSON("http://localhost/", function() {
     alert("success");
   })
   .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
   .error(function() { alert("error"); })
   .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
   }

and my server response is JSON string, but I still get "error" alert.

Comment: Have you tried to use Firebug to check if the server is responding with a 200 status code? Have you tried validating the JSON with http://jsonlint.com/ ?

Comment: JSON is correct, but I don't know exactly how server response should look like and I think there is a problem. As I said - I wrote server implementation on my own so I would be grateful if anyone will help mi with response's header.